# Generating the same input more multiple times

Tags: php, html, mysqli

The project I'm working on basically involves input boxes and storing them into a mysql database. I'm trying to use javascript to generate this form which can add another if needed. The problem I think i've ran into is getting it to assign a different "name" to the second generated form. ex red, red1, red2, etc. Then also trying to get that to work with php-mysqli.

So far i've been able to get it to post to the table but it's posting the values in the second set of input boxes. 
Can anybody offer some suggestions?

```js
<form id="color_form" action="postcolors.php" method="post">

<input id="name" class="color_entry" action="postcolors.php" method="post" name="name" placeholder="song name" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA…nt: scroll; background-position: right center; cursor: auto;"></input>
<input id="red" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="red" placeholder="red"></input>
<input id="green" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="green" placeholder="green"></input>
<input id="blue" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="blue" placeholder="blue"></input>
<input id="color" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="color" placeholder="color"></input>
<input id="name" class="color_entry" action="postcolors.php" method="post" name="name" placeholder="song name"></input>
<input id="red" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="red" placeholder="red"></input>
<input id="green" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="green" placeholder="green"></input>
<input id="blue" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="blue" placeholder="blue"></input>
<input id="color" class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="color" placeholder="color"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit" action="postcolors.php" method="post"></input>

</form>
```

```html
$song=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
$song = str_replace(' ', '', $song);
mysqli_query($connect, "CREATE TABLE $song (id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment, red int(2) NOT NULL, green int(2) NOT NULL, blue int(2) NOT NULL, color varchar(30) NOT NULL, index(id))");

$red=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['red']);
$green=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['green']);
$blue=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['blue']);
$color=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['color']);


mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO $song (red,green,blue,color) VALUES ('$red', '$green', '$blue', '$color')");
```

Comment: You can't repeat id, id="name" can only occur once in a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an `id=""` must be unique on a page so unless you are actually using the `id's` in javascript you can leave them off. If you are using them in javascript you will have to think of a way of making them unique.

Second you can ask the browser to return the field names as an array rather thana scalar value by using `name="color[]"` for example.

So change the name field like so :-

```
<form id="color_form" action="postcolors.php" method="post">

<input class="color_entry" action="postcolors.php" method="post" name="name[]" placeholder="song name" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA…nt: scroll; background-position: right center; cursor: auto;"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="red[]" placeholder="red"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="green[]" placeholder="green"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="blue[]" placeholder="blue"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="color[]" placeholder="color"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="postcolors.php" method="post" name="name[]" placeholder="song name"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="red[]" placeholder="red"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="green[]" placeholder="green"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="blue[]" placeholder="blue"></input>
<input class="color_entry" action="" method="post" name="color[]" placeholder="color"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit" action="postcolors.php" method="post"></input>

</form>
```

Now the $_POST will have $_POST['color'][0] and $_POST['color'][1] for example so you can change the processing to something like

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $idx => $name ) {

    mysqli_query($connect, 
                 "INSERT INTO $song (red,green,blue,color) 
                  VALUES ('{$_POST['red'][$idx']}', 
                          '{$_POST['green'][$idx']}', 
                          '{$_POST['blue'][$idx']}', 
                          '{$_POST['color'][$idx']}'
                         )"
                );
}
```

Comment: so post references by name, not ID? I wasn't aware of that. This looks like it might be what i'm trying to do.

Comment: The `id` is absolutely irrelevant to the PHP code, it only has a relevance if you are coding javascript.

Comment: I generate the form using javascript, so it would still be relevant right?

Comment: You only need the `id` if you are using javascript to look at or amend the contents of a tag. But then each `id` has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC one could use red[] as the name of the boxes, which would make $_POST['red'] an array to iterate over.